# Encoding Query string causes Error 500 DXA 1.4

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4, dxa-net

I am having this issue when I am sending an encoded query string. The server is returning a 500 Error.

I am using the js function `encodeURIComponent` to encode things in the front end and then use .NET decode function in the backend. For example:

> country=Finland&type=Sales+Partner
>
> country%3DFinland%26type%3DSales%2BPartner

I tried to check the validaterequest in the `web.config` but I don't think that is the problem, since the request does reach the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into similar issues as in this SO question,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005159/post-encodeuricomponent-query-string-internal-server-error-500